# delayed_job works only with rake jobs:workoff, not with RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have pretty simple task - I need to check if `submission` was assigned to developer within 2 minutes after it was created. And if not, send an email notifying about it.

App written in Rails4. I decided to use [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) gem.

```
after_create :unassigned_submission_pending_notification
def unassigned_submission_pending_notification 
  NotificationMailer.unassigned_submissions_pending(self).deliver if developer_id.nil?
end
  handle_asynchronously :unassigned_submission_pending_notification, run_at: Proc.new { 2.minutes.from_now }
```

In [documentation](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#gory-details) it is said to run `RAILS_ENV=production bin/delayed_job start` to make a worker do his job. But in my case this command do nothing, and only when I run `rake jobs:workoff` it works.

Any thoughts why?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec bin/delayed_job start
```

Or this:

```
rake jobs:work
```

Comment: doesn't work as well, unfortunately. Tried. Still only rake jobs:workoff fires the notification to be sent

Comment: any, apparently this made it work :). So do I use this command instead of mentioned in documentation?

Comment: Basically I think that `bin/delayed_job start` should start `rake jobs:work`. i'm not using `rake jobs:work` but I'm calling `bin/delayed_job start` directly from a deployment method using Capistrano. Maybe Capistrano start implicitly `rake jobs:work`. I've updated the answer by adding what work for you. If it's ok you can check the answer. :-)

Comment: Yeah, it does the thing, thank you :) Checked the answer, but can't vote it - do not have reputation(

Comment: The main part is that you problem is solved and that the community knows which answer was the good one. Everything is good.